# Can not resolve "$" underscore-java(java port for underscore.js)

Tags: java, underscore-java

```
$.each(asList(1, 2, 3), new Block<Integer>() {
    public void apply(Integer item) {
        System.out.println(item + ",");
    }
});
```

it throws error that it cannot resolve "$"
i am using underscore-java 1.6

Comment: Please show your import statements.

Comment: Have you imported the proper jar files whichever are  required? Also as a side **note** you can also try `Stream API` which is available for Java 8 (if you're using Java 8) if you want something on the lines of `underscore.js`

Comment: @Thilo - import com.github.underscore.Block this is the only import i can see :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `import com.github.underscore.$;`

Comment: Thanks it woks well now

Comment: com.github.underscore.$ was renamed to com.github.underscore.U.